# How to diagnose a problem with Azure DevOps build pipeline without re-running the pipeline every time you make a change?

Tags: azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline build that has several steps and the build is long. Every time there is something wrong with the build we review the logs and identify issues or come up with theories, then in case of a theory we have to insert a diagnostic command line  (such as get directory, show contents of a file, etc) in between the steps; and in case of a fix we add a fix but we have to wait for the whole pipeline to rerun and find out. This is causing us to take a lot of time to fix build issues.

If we had access to the state of the agent of an unfinished build and we could just log on using RDP or any other terminal and checkout the contents, and the state of the files on disk that would have saved us a lot of hours.

Is there any way with Azure DevOps to do any diagnostic of this type?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT No updates. I would love to be able to access the agent that has an unfinished build and my code, either by using RDP or SSH, or some other terminal protocol and run commands manually to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you are using hosted agent. If you are using self-hosted agent you can obviously log in to that one. You can, however, implement steps that only work if the build failed and those steps can attempt to capture information you are interested in (say publish the state of the build directory).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure DevOps *Services*, there is a new REST API version out that will let you do a "preview" run of changes to the YAML definitions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-165-update#preview-fully-parsed-yaml-document-without-committing-or-running-the-pipeline